# Deal other ID's in file?

Tags: python

i am working on my code which find minimum , maximum and sum of number on these two condition

1) Sum of all the 3rd element from those row which start from 1 and contain letter M , same for 507 and so on.

2) Find min and max number from all the 3rd element from those rows which start from 1 and contain Letter W , same for 507 and so on.From this list

Problem is that i have multiple lines in my file like this. Its just a sample

```
[['507', 'W', '1000', '1'],
['1', 'M', '6', '2'],
['1', 'W', '1400', '3'],
['1', 'M', '8', '8'],
['1', 'T', '101', '10'],
['507', 'M', '4', '12'],
['1', 'W', '1700', '15'],
['1', 'M', '7', '16'],
['507', 'M', '8', '20']]
```

my program give the exact output what i want but for this sample rows or for ID's 1 & 507 if there is more ID's in my file like 1 , 507 , 2 , 5 ,6 and so on how could i achieve this in my code

my code

```
     filename = '/home/salman/Desktop/input.txt'

rows = [['507', 'W', '1000', '1'],
['1', 'M', '6', '2'],
['1', 'W', '1400', '3'],
['1', 'M', '8', '8'],
['1', 'T', '101', '10'],
['507', 'M', '4', '12'],
['1', 'W', '1700', '15'],
['1', 'M', '7', '16'],
['507', 'M', '8', '20']]

lst2 = [item[0] for item in rows]
#print(lst2)
mylist = list(set(lst2))
print(mylist[0])

sum_1_M=0
sum_1_W=0
list_1=[]
count = 0
for i in range(len(mylist)):
 for x in rows:
    if x[0]== mylist[i] and x[1]=='M' :
        sum_1_M += int(x[2])
        count = count + 1
    elif  x[0]== mylist[i] and x[1]=='W':
           sum_1_W += int(x[2])
           list_1.append(int(x[2]))
           list_1.sort()
 print('{} {} {} {}'.format(mylist[i], list_1[0], list_1[len(list_1) - 1], int(sum_1_M/count)))
 sum_1_M = 0
 sum_1_W = 0
 list_1 = []
 count = 0
```

and output is this

```
1 1400 1700 21
507 1000 1000 12
```

output is fine but it only calculate for ID 1 and 507 . Where i need to change in my code to read other ID's and perform the same calculation on them and give the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you can try,

**UPDATE:**

```
L = [['507', 'W', '1000', '1'],
     ['1', 'M', '6', '2'],
     ['1', 'W', '1400', '3'],
     ['1', 'M', '8', '8'],
     ['1', 'T', '101', '10'],
     ['507', 'M', '4', '12'],
     ['1', 'W', '1700', '15'],
     ['1', 'M', '7', '16'],
     ['507', 'M', '8', '20']]

# initialize the dict with all ids
d = { x[0]: [] for x in L} # --> dict that stores keys as ids and values as list of list and you can store other ids here

for key in d:
    lst1 = [int(x[2]) for x in L if x[0] == str(key) and 'M' in x] #-> list of third elements satisfying first condition
    lst2 = [int(x[2]) for x in L if x[0] == str(key) and 'W' in x] #-> list of third elements satisfying second condition

    d[key].append(lst1)
    d[key].append(lst2)

    print('{} {} {} {}'.format(key, min(d[key][1]), max(d[key][1]), sum(d[key][0])))
```

**Output:**

```
1 1400 1700 21
507 1000 1000 12
```

Comment: your code is fine but you only deal it with 1 and 507 what if my input file looks like this `L = [['507', 'W', '1000', '1'],
     ['1', 'M', '6', '2'],
     ['1', 'W', '1400', '3'],
     ['1', 'M', '8', '8'],
     ['1', 'T', '101', '10'],
     ['507', 'M', '4', '12'],
     ['1', 'W', '1700', '15'],
     ['1', 'M', '7', '16'],
     ['507', 'M', '8', '20'],['2' , 'M' , '6' , '6'], ['2' ,'W' '7' '7'], [10,'W' ,'6' '7']]` now there is Id 2 and 10 how much ID i write in my code .

Comment: @LogitechFlames just and other ids in dictionary `d` as follows `d = { 1: [], 507: [], 2: [], 5:[], 6: []}` and so on..

Comment: the file is quite big and there's a lot of ID in it how many i write?

Comment: @LogitechFlames No need to add ids manually just add the ids to dict `d` dynamically when you are reading the file. for example d[507] = [] or d[2] = [] ...

Comment: will you please change it in your code? or should we do like this it read the first number from each row and store the unique id's in separate list and then iterate it 1 by 1?

Comment: @LogitechFlames You need to show me how you are actually reading the file and obtaining ids. so that i can update the answer properly. as per your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208719/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-logitech-flames).

Comment: @LogitechFlames check the updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: can you share some contact number or email so i can contact with you regarding this problem?